# Android :: Providing resources for 'similar' screens

Tags: android, resources, screen

I have a kind of tricky layout in my app, so the main problem is supporting different screens.
Let's take two phones HTC Sensation (4.3" 960x540 256dpi) and Droid (3.7" 854x480 265dpi), both of them use resources from `-normal-hdpi` while the difference in their resolution makes an interface completly improper!

Please suggest how to avoid this problem.

Comment: to be more specific here is an example: I have several `dimensions.xml`, it has `padding_side` parameter
for -ldpi `= 13dp`, for -mdpi `=11dp`, for -hdpi = `11dp`, for -large `=17dp`. For Sensation `14dp` suits best, but for Droid and S2 it remains `11dp`, while I cannot distinguish them in `-normal-hdpi`

Comment: Here my solution, not very smart but works..

`private void layoutCorrection(){

    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    if (dm.heightPixels == 960 && dm.widthPixels == 540){ 
        final int padding_side  = pxToDip(14);
        View myView = ...
        myView.setPadding(padding_side,0,padding_side,0);
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution

```
private void layoutCorrection(){ 
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 
if (dm.heightPixels == 960 && dm.widthPixels == 540){ 
final int padding_side = pxToDip(14); View myView = ... myView.setPadding(padding_side,0,padding_side,0); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have another units for android in this case..
use "dp" instead of px
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Mikhail you ALLWAYS should use dp.

Comment: Of course I use dp. Moreover for every ldpi/mdpi/hdpi case values which are declared in the corresponding 'dimensions' are not the same

Comment: you can read the page that I have referred. It will help you .. somewhere in the middle you have "support for multiple screen" it seems to address your poblem